# gateway solo 9550 windows xp

Tags: windows-xp

can i install a celeron 04 2.8 ghz cpu i currently have intel 01 1133 mhz

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking CPU upgrades in laptops are difficult to impossible.  In your case you definitely cannot swap.  The pentium 4 based celeron 4 is a very different chip from the pentium 3 that is currently in your machine.

Comment: While I differ with your "Generally", in this case the proposed swap really is hopeless. If he has a Celeron, a move to Pentium III Processor-M may be possible. Maybe.